# jQuery loading PartialView in ASP.NET times out

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, partial-views

I am using jQuery to load PartialView's onto a webpage, triggered by button clicks. This works without issue when the page first loads, but if the page experiences inactivity for a few minutes button clicks will fail to load the PartialViews. No error message is displayed.

Here's the code:

```
$loadPage = function (page) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.get("/PartialView/" + page, function (data) {
            $("#output").html(data);
        });
    }, 100);
}

<div id="button" onclick="$loadPage('page1');"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: You probably have an error elsewhere, did you check your console (F12)

Comment: inspect requests in browser console for clues...are requests made? what is status etc...could be caching issue

Comment: `"No error message is displayed."` - But is there an error *at all*?  What is the response from the server?

Comment: Why don't you use Html.Partial("PartialViewName") ?

Comment: I realise this was asked a few days ago, but in Firefox console I get a 500 internal server error when this problem occurs. The request for the PartialView is sent but the server does not respond. In the response headers, the connection is set as "close".